# How to git clone (done), Cmake build (almost done) and run a C++ Project in Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, c++, cmake

This is my first day in Ubuntu (20.04.4 LTS) for C++ development. Previously I only used Windows, and find something new to work with. I would appreciate your support.

1. After cloning a [github repo](https://github.com/ingowald/optix7course), I tried to build with `CMake ..` from terminal. But it returned some errors, as my repo heavily depends on some external libraries that need to manually select. So I used traditional `CMake GUI`.
2. In  `Windows CMake GUI` I could select the `current visual studio version` and the `framework (for my case only x64)`. But in `Ubuntu GUI` I did not see such options. I am using `VS Code` and `gcc` compiler. As the `CMakeGUI` not showing any of these options, **which option  I should  select**?? I could see `Codeblock IDEs` there.
3. One the CMake Config, and Generate, in Windows I could find the solution (`.sln`) file to reopen the C++ code base. **How in Ubuntu I can reopen the project from build folder**???

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? You have tagged Ubuntu 14.04, which has reached end of support three years ago.

Comment: `But it returned some errors` -- What all errors?

Comment: my bad, it is Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi, its not error, it is actually how to. I thought `ask ubuntu` I can also ask it, can't I?

Comment: What GitHub repo are you trying to build? Can you edit the question to post a link?

Comment: https://github.com/ingowald/optix7course

Comment: Did you follow this? https://github.com/ingowald/optix7course#building-under-linux What was the issue?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi , my main problem was nvcc compiler during running the project. I solved it. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my first-time programming under Linux environment, so many simply things were unknown to me. Here, how I proceed:

1. The errors are mostly created because of the CMake file and external dependencies. If the CMake file is not well constructed, it may not access some of the external libraries easily during configure and generate.
2. Using CMake GUI is similar to Windows environment. However, during `Configure` few options would pop-up. If you do not know specifically the IDE, compiler info, I would suggest using `Unix Makefiles`. This option perfectly worked for `CLion`.
3. As there is no `.sln (solution)` file in Ubuntu, you can simply open the project repository, and run it in `CLion`. You may check drop down option in `BUILD/RELEASE`. In case there are multiple projects, you need to select the same project option from drop down.

In this short test project, my main problem was `CUDA Toolkit and NVCC` compiler integration as I was working on a graphics project. Hope this will help others in future.